# Where can i find the System.Json.dll for Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, json, silverlight, windows-phone-8

According to the following document I should have a dll called `System.Json.dll` but I don't have it: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Where can I get it? I preffer this approach rather tan using `DataContractJsonSerializer` as the response has weird attribute names and then I would need a class with the same weird names on its properties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I preffer to stick to 'official' code when it is available.

Comment: Whats wrong with Json.NET? Far the best Library for using Json in .NET

Comment: Nothing wrong but I preffer to reduce dependencies when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assembly can be found in the following folder (on a 64-bit system):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\vX.0\Libraries\Client
```

(or *C:\Program Files* on a 32-bit system), where *X* in *vX.0* is either *3*, *4* or *5*.

The *System.Json.dll* assembly should be listed among the **Extensions** assemblies in the *Add References* dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, here is the info for the dlls:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client\System.Json.dll

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client\System.Xml.Linq.dll
```

but for SL 4, I only see

```
c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\System.Xml.dll
```

no `System.Xml.Linq.dll`

In VS when try to add reference to SL Prokect, no System.Xml.Linq.dll available.

Comment: I only have SL4 and 5 and System.Json is not there :\